# Array incorrectly Displaying the textfile

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to read a textfile into my array but it is adding 0s at the end of the output up until the size of the array. I think the problem is with the way I read the textfile.

I used a foreach loop to display the array but it does the same thing.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int size = 10000;
    int[] Array = new int[size];

    StreamReader SR = new StreamReader("Data.Txt");

    int i = 0;           
    while (!SR.EndOfStream)
    {
        Array[i] = int.Parse(SR.ReadLine());
        i++;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("ARRAY BEFORE SORTING" );

    for (int x = 0; x <= Array.Length-1 ; x++)
    {
            Console.WriteLine(Array[x]);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The code outputs the normal numbers in the textfile but then adds uneccessary 900 0s afterwards

Comment: You can use `List<int>`. Array is fixed size and that is why this happens.

Comment: `int[] Array = File.ReadLines("Data.Txt").Select(item => int.Parse(item)).ToArray();`

Comment: for (int x = 0; x < i ; x++)

Answer (score 2):

Following is an easy way of doing this. (There are many others way of achieving this. You may find different answers. I found that you are using basic code blocks.)

**Problem**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int size = 10000;
        int[] Array = new int[size];
```

You are creating an array with 10000 items assigned with 0 (default). So those items which are not assigned with value from text file will remain 0 forever.

**Solution**

Create array based on number of values in text file.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(YOUR_FILE PATH);

int[] array = new int[lines.Length];

int i =0; 
foreach(var line in lines)
{
    array[i] = int.Parse(line);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: great answer but why not using `for` and get the `i` from there?

Comment: @styx Thanks for the suggestion. I think for this small code, it won't make any difference. I used for easy understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You don't know the `size`, before hand, do you?

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       // File is non necessary has exactly 10000 items it can have, say, 100 ones
       int size = 10000; 
       int[] Array = new int[size];
```

When you create an array - `int[] Array = new int[size];` - you've got it - `10000` items each of them `0`; then
you rewrite first `9100` of them when last `900` are still `0`.

The easist way to obtain a correct array is *Linq*:

```
   using System.Linq;
   ...

   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       int[] Array = File
         .ReadLines("Data.Txt")
         .Select(item => int.Parse(item))
         .ToArray();

       Console.WriteLine("ARRAY BEFORE SORTING");
       ...
```

If you want to amend you current code, use `List<int>` instead of array to collect items:

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       int size = 10000;
       List<int> items = new List<int>();

       // using: Do not forget to close the file (via IDisposable) 
       using (StreamReader SR = new StreamReader("Data.Txt")) 
       {
           while (!SR.EndOfStream) 
           {
              items.Add(int.Parse(SR.ReadLine()));
           } 
       } 

       // Now either int[] Array = items.ToArray(); or
       int[] Array = new int[items.Count]; // <- no necessary 10000

       for (int i = 0; i < Array.Length; ++i)
          Array[i] = items[i];

       Console.WriteLine("ARRAY BEFORE SORTING");
       ...
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create any variable in `c#` it will be initialized to it's a predefined default value.

In your case, an int[] will be assigned to {0,0,0,0.....} which means that you have an array with 10000 zeros in it, but you set number until some number (which is lower than 10000) so you will get, for example, {1,2,3,0,0,0,...}.

you can change the size if you know the array length before.
Or you a `List<int>` which a is dynamic array, and you can read all about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8)

here's an example use

```
           List<int> Array = new List<int>(); // must be intalized otherwise you will get null exception

            using (StreamReader SR = new StreamReader("Data.Txt")) //to prevent memorey leaks
            {

                while (!SR.EndOfStream)
                {  
                    Array.Add(int.Parse(SR.ReadLine()));                     

                } 
            }   

            Console.WriteLine("ARRAY BEFORE SORTING");

            for (int x = 0; x <= Array.Count - 1; x++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Array[x]);
            }   

            Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is only because you create an array of size '10000', even if they are empty, the foreach will loop on you 10000 empty element in your array.
If you know the length of your element, use this to create you array. Else use a List.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<int> array = new List<int>();

    StreamReader SR = new StreamReader("Data.Txt");

    while (!SR.EndOfStream)
    {
        array.Add(int.Parse(SR.ReadLine()));
    }
    Console.WriteLine("ARRAY BEFORE SORTING" );

    for (int x = 0; x < array.Count; x++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(array[x]);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: I tried to change my code to an ArrayList, but when I do that my Sorting Methods do not work

Answer (score 0):

You can use nullable `int` array instead. In that, the default value will be `null` and you will not get any 0s appended to your text.

```
int size = 10000;
int?[] Array = new int?[size];
```